# Editing single or all selected users in a table with checkboxes - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, html-table, edit

I'm loading a JSON into a table. I want my 'edit' button to edit a single row and my 'edit selected' to edit only those rows which are checked, but I can't figure it out. I only managed to get it to edit all rows at once.

`example.json`

```
{
    "example": [
        {
            "first": "something1",
            "second": "one"
        },
        {
            "first": "something2",
            "second": "two"
        },
        {
            "first": "something3",
            "second": "three"
        },
        {
            "first": "something4",
            "second": "four"
        }
    ]
}
```

`index.htm`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-app="newApp" ng-controller="newCtrl">
        <h1>
            <button ng-click="showFunc()">Edit selected</button>
        </h1>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>First </th>
                <th>Second</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="iterator in newData.example" ng-show="show">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </td>
                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="iterator.first">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="iterator.second">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="showFunc()">Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="iterator in newData.example" ng-show="!show">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </td>
                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td>{{iterator.first}}</td>
                <td>{{iterator.second}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="showFunc()">Edit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>



        <script>
            var app = angular.module('newApp', []);
            app.controller('newCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get("example.json")
                    .then(function (response) {
                        $scope.newData = response.data;
                    });
                $scope.show = false;
                $scope.showFunc = function (index) {
                    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
                }

            });
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question, not on external sites.

Comment: it wouldn't let me cause 'too long', that's why i used pastebin

Comment: Hmm. I tried editing it in and it worked fine.

Comment: thanks, I don't know why but it wouldn't let me post the whole thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a show variable for each `iterator`. As it is coded now, you have one, single variable that controls the view state for all the rows. Does that make logical sense? Nope.

The easiest way to get a `show` variable for each row, is to create a reference to it on the iterator itself:

```
<tr ng-repeat="iterator in newData.example" ng-show="iterator.show">
  ...
    <td>
      <button ng-click="showFunc(iterator)">Save</button>
    </td>
</tr>

 <tr ng-repeat="iterator in newData.example" ng-show="!iterator.show">
    ...
    <td>
      <button ng-click="showFunc(iterator)">Edit</button>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

Since it is initially `undefined` it will be treated as falsey, and the row will show up in the non-edit state.

Then in your controller make sure you are setting the individual show variable:

```
$scope.showFunc = function (iterator) {
  iterator.show = !iterator.show;
}
```

To select multiple rows, you follow the same pattern. Add a `selected` property by referencing it in your checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="iterator.selected"/>
```

`iterator.selected` will automatically update each time you click the checkbox.

Now, here I assume somewhere you have a global `Edit Selected` button somewhere on your page:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="editSelected()">Edit Selected</button>
```

Now in your controller you will have to do some work to set the `show` variable only on the items in the list where `selected` is true:

```
$scope.editSelected() = function() {
  $scope.newData.example.filter(function(iterator) {
    return iterator.selected;
  }).forEach(function(item) {
    item.show = true;
  });
}
```

If you don't recognize this filtering pattern, be sure to read the [Array docs on MDN documentation website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: right, so I have an iterator for each row. but it's only in the table, i can't see it in the controller, can i? it won't work with my previous $scope.show as iterator.show

Comment: You are passing the iterator as a parameter to your `showFunc`. That's how you can access it. Every time you click a Save or Edit button, you are passing that individual iterator to the `showFunc` to change it's status

Comment: i got it! thanks, now i can edit single rows. but it still doesn't work for selecting multiple rows i.e. check 2 and 3 and edit those. can you point me in the right direction here?